# How to compare .SQL File statements (SQL Queries) are executed in Database or not?

Tags: java, sql, database, automated-tests, development-environment

Excellent if you can read and suggest/help on this. Thanks in Advance.

I'm working on some database related automation process. we're facing issue at below scenario.

In general, we can compare two SQL Files and that can be done using file reader class in Java
and Also we can compare database results by using result set concept in SQL SERVER & Java.

Here, in our case, we'd like to compare :

1. Database file (.SQL) it has N number of lines of SQL Statements (such as Create, Alter, Store procedures and so on)
2. We should get this values from the file line by  line (It's done)
3. And we should compare whether this above statements are available in Database or not? and It's executed or not.

I want to crack the 3rd point.

If you need more information, please comment here, I'll provide the same.

Thank you,

Rajesh Bathula

Comment: Hi Arvind Kumar, Yes, I want to check whether these all the statements are matched in Database or not.

Comment: **Any Suggestions** please